# Laravel 5.6, Form submit does nothing but page reload

Tags: php, laravel-5

My problem is that when a form is being submitted just reloads the page without doing anything. 
My route looks like this:

```
Route::post('/subscription/cancel', 'SubscriptionController@cancelSubscription')->name('cancel');
```

My form:

```
<form class="subscription-action--forms" action="{{ route('cancel') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input id="cancel-input" type="submit" value="Cancel Subscription">
</form>
```

And finally my SubscriptionController `cancelSubscription()` method, which is not being executed:

```
public function cancelSubscription() {
    if (auth()->user()->isSubscribed()) {
        auth()->user()->subscription('Subscription to Ebooks.am')->cancel();

        return redirect('/subscription')->with('info', 'Canceled!');
    } 

    return redirect('/subscription');
}
```

The interesting thing is that this code worked just fine until some point (maybe due to a change in other files, don't know).

Comment: `auth()->user()->isSubscribed()` is returning falsy value, so you are getting redirected, check there for any bugs

Comment: Because in both cases you're redirecting back so what else does it suppose to do?

Comment: No, If I add say dd('something goes here') in the first line of the function, it's not being executed either.

Comment: The problem is that the function is not being executed at all, it's not being reached even.

Comment: is you route name on your blade file a valid/existing route name? is it found on `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: yes, it can be found.

Comment: have you tried `php artisan route:clear` `php artisan view:clear` ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but just did it and no effect. 
Thank you for your efforts, man. I do appreciate it!

Comment: do you have a `store()` method inside that controller? can you please check if it is executing that method?

Comment: I don't have exactly `store()` method but I have a lot of different methods in the same controller which work correctly.

Comment: you said that it is working before, can you please run `php artisan config:cache` ?

Comment: I did, but no change again. But when I tried `php artisan route:cache` I get an error, I guess the problem is connected to the error